# match 1,2,5 columns of file1 with 1,2,3 columns of file2 respectively and output should have matched rows from file 2. second file is zipped file .gz

Tags: linux, awk, vcftools, bcftools

file1

```
3   1234581 A   C   rs123456
```

file2 zipped file .gz

```
1   1256781 rs987656    T   C
3   1234581 rs123456    A   C
22  1792471 rs928376    G   T
```

output

```
3   1234581 rs123456    A   C
```

I tried

```
zcat file2.gz | awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$5]++;next} a[$1,$2,$3]' file1.txt  - > output.txt
```

but it is not working

Comment: Did you try anything at all? It's customary to show some trials, good or bad.

Comment: yes I have updated the bash command I used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following `awk` code for your shown samples. Use `zcat` to read your .gz file and then pass it as 2nd input to `awk` program for reading, after its done reading with file1.

```
zcat your_file.gz | awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1,$2,$5];next} (($1,$2,$3) in arr)' file1 -
```

Fixes in OP's attempt:

- You need not to increment value of array while creating it in file1. Just existence of indexes in it will be enough.
- While checking condition in reading file2(passed by zcat command) just check if respective fields are present in array if yes then print that line.

Comment: I need to match columns 1,2,5 of file1 together to column 1,2,3 of second zipped file

Comment: @rij, yes please check my updated answer(refresh this page) I have updated my answer, let me know.

Comment: 'FNR==NR{arr[$1,$2,$5];next} ($1,$2,$3 in arr)' wont work right ?

Comment: @rij, I have tested it and it worked fine for me with your shown samples. use file2 with zcat command and pass file1 as input file to `awk` program.